# $\Gamma$-convergence and choice of sequence

Tags: functional-analysis

$\Gamma$-convergence is a useful notion of convergence of functionals. It is useful because it guarantees that the corresponding minimizers of the functionals also converge to the minimizer of the limit functional.

The usual $\Gamma$-convergence type of proof is like: let $u_n \rightarrow u$ for $u_n, u$ in some function space -- let's say the Sobolev space $W^{1,2}[0,1]$. Then we want to show that $\lim\inf_{n\rightarrow \infty} T_n(u_n) \geq T(u)$ and $\lim\sup_{n\rightarrow \infty} T_n(u_n) \leq T(u)$.

**I want to know whether it suffices to show that this limit holds for some sequence $u_n \rightarrow u$ rather than for all sequences.** For example if I construct a sequence of stepfunction approximations $u_n$ of $u$, will this be enough to show the $\Gamma$-convergence generally? Are there certain topologies for the convergence $u_n \rightarrow u$ where this works and others where this doesn't work?

If it's not true that we can simply show the limit for one particular sequence, is there any additional condition that can make it true? E.g. the stronger limit $T_n(u_n) \rightarrow T(u)$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ instead of the limsup and liminf inequalities.

Comment: Actually you need to show the limsup inequality just for one particular sequence $u_n \rightarrow u$ (which is called a optimizing sequence or recovery sequence). Look better at the definition of $\Gamma$-convergence

Comment: @DarkMagician sure. but this is not true for the liminf inequality.

Comment: Ok ok, I just wanted to clarify this point, since it is not written in the question

Comment: @DarkMagician yeah, thanks!